# Grow :before content width from center

Tags: css

I've recently discovered the following approach for text-progress styling and wonder if there is a workaround to grow the element width from the center, so the text would also fill the from center instead of from the left side.

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 85px;
  position: relative;
}

p:before {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 85px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  animation: background-fill 15s ease-in-out infinite forwards;
}
  
@keyframes background-fill {
  0% {
    width: 0;
   }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<p data-text='Text'>Text</p>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve that by also animate `left` and `text-indent`

I also changed your `p` to display as inline-block, so it animate the text and not white space.

*Thanks to [Gaby aka G. Petrioli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44379569/grow-before-content-width-from-center/44379715#comment75760199_44379605), it appears Firefox have issue with percent-based `text-indent`, so I added a CSS hack to overcome that. And again thanks to Gaby, for his now delete answer, that solved the Firefox issue (though unfortunately fails on IE)*

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
}

p {
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 85px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

p:before {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 0;
  height: 85px;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  content: attr(data-text);
  display: block;
  animation: background-fill 5s ease-in-out infinite forwards;
}
  
@keyframes background-fill {
  0% {
    left: 50%;
    text-indent: -50%;
    width: 0;
   }
  100% {
    left: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
    width: 100%;
  }
}

/*  Begin - Firefox bug fix  */
@supports (-moz-appearance:meterbar) and (display:flex) {
  p:before {
    width: auto;
    right: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
  }
  @keyframes background-fill {
    0% {
      right: 50%;
      left: 50%;
    }
    100% {
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
  }
}
/*  End - Firefox bug fix  */
```

```html
<p data-text='Text'>Text</p>
```

---

An alternative to the CSS hack, is a small script, that, on page load, measure the actual width of the element and set the `text-indent` as `px` instead of `%`.

Comment: LGSon no idea how someone could downvote your answer :) works fantastic, thank you a lot! :)

Comment: just a heads-up: In FF this does not work (*the text moves from center to left*)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks again...updated my answer with a Firefox CSS hack, where I used your version (hope it is okay) to solve Firefox's issue with percent based `text-indent`